# send email with outlook address C#?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, smtp, sendmail

I want to send email with Outlook address, if I want simply send with outlook I need enter url in navigator like 'mail.xxx.com', then Outlook web apps shows, I enter username/domaine and password, so I want to do this in C#, this is the code:

```
string client_Host = "";
int client_Port = 0;

if (cmb_Destinataire.Text.ToLower().Contains("hotmail"))
{
    client_Host = "smtp.live.com";
    client_Port = 465;
}
else if (cmb_Destinataire.Text.ToLower().Contains("gmail"))
{
    client_Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    client_Port = 587;
}
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(cmb_De.Text, cmb_Destinataire.Text.Trim(), txt_Objet.Text, txtDescription.Text);

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(client_Host, client_Port);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password","domaine");
client.SendAsync(msg,"test");

MessageBox.Show("sent", "Validation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

but I don't receive any email.

Comment: Do you get an error message?Also try using  the client.Send so that the messagebox is shown after the email is sent

Comment: no i dont get any error !! even if i change SendAsync to send

Answer (score 0):

`client.SendAsync(msg,"test");` is an asynchronized method. so the messagebox following it wont tell you that the email was really sent. the message box will fire in either way. you are probably missing an exception thrown in another thread.
consider implementing the following callback:

```
private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the unique identifier for this asynchronous operation.
             String token = (string) e.UserState;

            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Send canceled.", token);
            }
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", token, e.Error.ToString());
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");
            }
        }
```

and don't forget to register your callback

```
client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
```

Comment: thank's you for your answers , where i should put my callback "client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);" , when i put it after message.SendAsync , i dont get any message , i think that's not the right code for sending mail from Outlook adress to another adress ? , and thank's for help :)

Comment: you should register your callback before calling the SendAsync.

Comment: @GeorgeVovos he's probably receiving an error during the async call which is not caught in the main thread. furthermore, the exception isn't being thorwn but instead it is sent through the parameters of the SendCompletedCallback